# OpenCV Blob detector using Laplacian

Tags: c++, opencv

I've got a image from a microscope and need to analyse it (isolate blobs). I've been trying a lot of methods in order to threshold and filter the image which gave me good results, now I'm trying to get the best results.

I've been reading about the Laplace operator and applying the Lapacian of Gauss to found zero-crossing, which are edges of the image.

I've implemented [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/laplace_operator/laplace_operator.html) code to my subject image, I can view the Laplacian results but I don't know how to "use" it since it's in other "space" (depth)

Here are the subject image and the Laplace result. How can I get blobs from Laplace image?

[image: subject]

[image: laplacian]

Comment: didn't try it out but maybe (gaussian +) watershed ?

Comment: I've tryed watershed but I get a very poor segmentation

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already done the laplace on the input image, The next step you need to do is:

- Threshold the image to obtain a binary image.
- Find contours(blobs) in the binary image.

The sample code may look like:

```
laplacian_img_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(laplacian_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(laplacian_img, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# For debugging Purposes
for i in xrange(len(contours)):
    laplacian_img_RGB = cv2.drawContours(laplacian_img_RGB, contours, i, [0, 255, 0], 3)

cv2.imwrite("./debug.png", laplacian_img_RGB)
```

Comment: The problem is the pixel depth of the Laplacina result (CV_64F) and all the steps you suggested need a CV_8 depth image and that's the problem I was facing. But I solved it using **convertScaleAbs**